# Prove that $f'(x)+e^{-x}=0$ has at least one real root

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity

Let $f$ be continuously differentiable on $(0;+\infty)$ and $f(0)=1$. Prove that if $|f(x)|\leq e^{-x}$ for $x\geq 0$, then there is $x_0>0$ such that $f'(x_0)+e^{-x_0}=0$

I considered the function $g(x)=f(x)-e^{-x}$
Clearly, $g(0)=0$. Since $|f(x)|\leq e^{-x}\Rightarrow g(x)\leq 0$ for $x\geq 0$.
If there is $x_0\in (0;+\infty)$ such that $g(x_0)$ is the maximum value of $g$ on $(0;+\infty)(*)$, I can use Fermat's theorem to prove $g'(x_0)=0\Leftrightarrow f'(x_0)+e^{-x_0}=0$.
But I don't assure about $(*)$. Is this correct? I need some help.
Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Context? What have you tried so far? We like to help, but we are not a homework answering service!

Comment: Dear Mike, I edited my post. Thank you for your prompt!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ETA: I saw your proof** it is correct, the desired $x_0$ is indeed $x_0$ a maximum of your $g(x)$.

This is the proof sketched out, some details are left for you to fill in.

Let us write $y(x) \doteq e^{-x}$. Then the conditions $f(x)=1; |f(x)| \le |y(x)|=y(x)$; $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} y(x) = 0$ give the following:

Writing $g(x) = y(x)-f(x)$, the function $g(x)$ satisfies $g(0) = 0; \ $
$0 \le g(x) \le 2$ for all $x$; and $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} g(x) = 0$.

So unless $g$ is 0 everywhere [in which case we are done], there is an $x_0 > 0$ such that $g$ achieves its [positive] maximum at $x=x_0$.

What can we say about $g'(x)$ at $x=x_0$ then. Note then that $g'(x) = -(e^{-x}+f'(x))$.

Can you finish from here.

Comment: Ohhh. Thank you for your clear explanation <3